# Телеграм бот на Питоне не выдает данные из таблицы, помогите

Tags: aiogram, xampp, mysqlconnector, python-3.9

Написал телеграм бот на питоне который должен выводить данные из sql таблицы.

Бот запускается и отправляет ответ на стартовую команду, но после не выдает ничего из таблицы. ни ошибок, ни предупреждении. Bспользую PyCharm Community и xampp.

```
import logging
import mysql.connector
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types

API_TOKEN = 'token'

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    password="",
    database="php"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Привет!\nВведите имя:")
# работает до этой строчки


@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def send_msg(message: types.Message):
    mycursor.execute(
        "SELECT surname, age, year, city, phone FROM list WHERE name ='{}'".format(message.from_user.id))
    # fetching the rows from the cursor object
    result = mycursor.fetchone()
    for x in result:
        await message.answer(x)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите чтобы после команды start бот выводил данные с таблицы то сделайте так.

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    mycursor.execute(
        "SELECT surname, age, year, city, phone FROM list WHERE name ='{}'".format(message.from_user.id))
    result = mycursor.fetchone()
    for x in result:
        await message.answer(x)
```

Comment: не работает, данные все равно не выводятся.

Comment: Принтани Х и отправь сюда